# jstl tags do not link with jsp variables

Tags: jstl

ím trying to add jstl/jsp component to a spring+flex+hibernate project. Im using Tomcat 5, downloaded and added the jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2 dependencies, made some changes to the web.xml, etc... dont want to get drifted away from my current problem, this piece of code:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10" step="1">
     <c:out value="${i}" />
      sip!
     <br />
   </c:forEach>
```

At the jsp file, Prints this:

${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!
${i} sip!

So for what i understand here, the jstl tag is working, but not the jsp?
However, this code:

```
<%
  for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
{%>
<%=i%><br/>
<%
}
%>
```

prints this:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

So here, jsp is working with variables.

I never used jsp/jstl before, neither together or separate. However for what i understand, both tags work fine on my setup, how ever they don´t work together, variables are not linking ?? this right ? how can i fix it?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Got it working! problem was on my web.xml, matched the header with the one described here for my version: http://faq.javaranch.com/java/ServletsWebXml.

Hope this helps some one. One meta question, should i answer my own question ? or leave it like this ?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to answer your own question if no one has done it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Got it working! problem was on my web.xml, matched the header with the one described here for my version: http://faq.javaranch.com/java/ServletsWebXml.